# Getting org.apache.poi.EmptyFileException while writing unit test case for a java function using spock

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have this below unit test case for a java function:

```
def "should generate claims error file"(){
    given:
    def tempFile = new TempFile()
    def excelErrorRecord = new ExcelErrorRecord(row: 5, col: 4, message: "Test Message")
    HashMap<String, List<ExcelErrorRecord>> errorRecords = new HashMap<>();
    errorRecords.put("Medical",[excelErrorRecord])
    def fileInputStream = Mock(FileInputStream)
    def workBook = Mock(Workbook)
    def file = Mock(File)

    and:
    tempFile.getFile() >> file
    file.length() >> 100
    tempFile.getFile().getAbsolutePath() >> "Temp File.xlsx"
    new FileInputStream(tempFile.getFile().getAbsolutePath()) >> fileInputStream
    new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream) >> workBook

    when:
    service.generateClaimsErrorFile(errorRecords, tempFile)

    then:
    noExceptionThrown()
  }
```

This test case is to execute the following piece of java function:

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempFile.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
         Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis)) 
{}
catch(){}
```

The above test case is throwing `org.apache.poi.EmptyFileException` at the line `Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis)`. How can I fix this and what's the cause for this issue ?

Comment: You are getting a new temp file. Why are you surprised it's empty?

Comment: Why do you mock such basic things like files and your excel library?

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to mock `File` or `FileInputStream`. Just use Spock's `@TempFile` extension to setup a temporary file with the necessary content.

This looks like you expect it to be mocked

```
  new FileInputStream(tempFile.getFile().getAbsolutePath()) >> fileInputStream
  new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream) >> workBook
```

however that is not how it works.

Try something along these lines, as I'm not familiar with Apache POI the example might not work, but it should get you started.

```
class ASpec extends Specification {
  @TempFile
  File tempFile


  def "should generate claims error file"(){
    given: 'setup test workbook'
    def testWorkBook = XSSFWorkbook()
    // add some testdata to workbook

    and: 'save workbook'
    tempFile.withOutputStream { testWorkBook.write(it) }

    and:
    def excelErrorRecord = new ExcelErrorRecord(row: 5, col: 4, message: "Test Message")
    HashMap<String, List<ExcelErrorRecord>> errorRecords = new HashMap<>();
    errorRecords.put("Medical",[excelErrorRecord])


    when:
    service.generateClaimsErrorFile(errorRecords, tempFile)

    then:
    noExceptionThrown()
}
```

Comment: Still I'm getting the same empty file exception

Comment: @Thiluxan If you have new insights, then please edit your question, so we can see the progress and add your new errors.